# Large list backup in sharepoint online - suggested way

Tags: sharepoint-online, splistitem, list-view-threshold, content-migration

we need to backup a large list in our sharepoint online environment, the following things needs to be considered

1. The List has more than 10000 items
2. The List has a lookup column
3. Our environment does not allow SCA Access granted to users to run powershell script or to use Tools like ShareGate/ Metalogix content matrix.
4. Save list as template cannot be used has it has more than 5000 items in the list.

what would be the best way to copy these items so that these items are safe..

Comment: Have you tried Export to Excel?

Comment: Export to excel should work. Do you need the metadata?